# Custom status code page with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I've project in ASP NET Core 3.1 with Windows Authentication. I would like to use custom error code page.
This a basic example.

In HomeController :

```
 [Route("/Error/401")]
    public IActionResult StatusCode401()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return View("ErrorUnauthorized");
    }
```

But when I call StatusCode401 method, Windows prompt dialog (login, password) appears, if I cancel it, I see my custom view.
If I disable Windows Authentication, it's works fine.

How disable Windows prompt dialog when I use  Windows Authentication ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the web.config,

And then find the **statusCode 401**, change the **responseModel** from **ExecuteURL** to **File**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
        <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="***" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="401" subStatusCode="2" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="***" responseMode="File" />
        ....
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works fine. But finaly we leave Windows Authentication....